# Select the first and last word in a comma separated string SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to solve a seemingly easy task, but can't find the exact solution.

I have a string with comma separated categories in MySQL, such as: Beauty, Cosmetics, Perfume

I would like to get only the first and last word (category) from the string.  **Beauty** or **Perfume**.

I have been trying numerous solutions like this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(categories, CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(categories))-1) FROM data
```

but each of them doesn't work in my case.

It doesn't matter how many words the string contain, I only need the first and last word of this string.

In addition, I need to implement such values in another query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE type = '$type' AND ^^^WHAT I NEED^^^ = '$first_category' AND item_type = '$item_type' AND slug = '$slug'
```

It would be perfect if I could cope with both tasks in just one query.

Comment: If you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thank you for a hint. In my case it still doesn't work. But I grasped that I should study the SUBSTRING_INDEX.

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected result set.

Comment: Ideally, I want this string to work: $query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE type = '$type' AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(categories, ',', 1) = '$primary_category' AND item_type = '$item_type' AND slug = '$slug'"; as I wrote in my initial question -- I need to extract the 1st category from categories and the last one. At least the 1st one.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Beauty, Cosmetics, Perfume',',',1)n;
+--------+
| n      |
+--------+
| Beauty |
+--------+

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Beauty, Cosmetics, Perfume',',',-1)n;
+----------+
| n        |
+----------+
|  Perfume |
+----------+
```

Comment: I was trying this query "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(categories, ',', 1 ) FROM data" with no results. In my case the string categories contains "Beauty, Cosmetics, Perfume"